# vue show either "submit" or "update" button

Tags: vue.js

I want to show the **update** button when the **userId** matches with one of the **previous users** & if the **userId** & one of the **previous users** doesn't match then it will show the **submit** button.

I am trying this way---

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function() {
        return {
          userId:1,
          previousUsers:[1,2],
        }
      },
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(previousUser,i) in previousUsers" :key="i" class="text-center mt-3">
                  <button v-if="previousUser == userId" class="btn btn-primary" @click="update">Update</button>
                  <button v-if="previousUser == !userId" class="btn btn-primary" @click="add">Submit</button>
                </div></div>
```

In my way the **submit** button doesn't show if I change the **userId** to "3". How to solve this?

Comment: Check the `v-if` condition for the second button. `!userId` converts it to a boolean before the comparison, and given the values of `userId` it will always be `false`. You may have meant to write `v-if="previousUser != userId"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through all the previous users and making comparisons with the current user, so you will display one button for each user. If this is your intent you are just writing the second condition in a wrong way: instead of `previousUser == !userId` it should be `previousUser != userId`, but this way changing the `userId` to `3` will make the program render 2 submit buttons, because each previous user you are cycling through is different from the current user id.

Instead, if you want to show **just ONE button**, and the button should be `update` if `userId` is in the previous user ids array and `submit` otherwise, I suggest you to use a `computed` property to decide which button to render, and not to use a `v-for`. For example:

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function() {
        return {
          userId:1,
          previousUsers:[1,2],
        }
      },
      computed: {
        isUserInPreviousUsers() {
          return this.previousUsers.indexOf(this.userId) >= 0;
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
    <button v-if="isUserInPreviousUsers" class="btn btn-primary" @click="update">Update</button>
    <button v-else class="btn btn-primary" @click="add">Submit</button>
```